# how to open the website in the webserver it self

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5

I've got a webserver installed windows 2008 R2, IIS 7.5,

1 dedicated IP Address

from here I'm hosting several wesites....
like www.abc.com
     www.efg.com
     www.hkl.com

via bindings I'm routing the websites and it works fine. I can access these websites from other PC.

so until here it works fine....

But I like to access these websites from the webserver it self.  how can I do that?

e.g. I tried. 214.xxx.xxx.xxx\abc.com  and I also tried localhost\abc.om

But I get the error BELOW....

## Question:

so my question is how can access these domains in in the WEBSERVER it self... All of them are created as website and the are running independently Application pool.... (not in defaut website)

All those are ASP.NET web application. V2.0 and V4.0

### Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error 
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

Source Error:

Line 116:  
Line 117:  
Line 118:    
Line 119:    
Line 120:

Source File: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc\web.config    Line: 118

Show Additional Configuration Errors:

It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc\web.config line 202)
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc\web.config line 261)
It is an error to use a section registered as allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS. (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\abc\web.config line 262)

---

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5456; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding an Application, instead of a Virtual Directoy.  It sounds like your Virtual Directory is an application.

I think the error is happening because the web.config at the virtual directory folder is the root web.config for an application.  This config is conflicting with the web.config at the Default Web Site level.

Comment: Yes you're right... that was my problem.. thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1):

The websites you have on your web server are configured via virtual directories. You need to put the name of the folder after the server name. 
try:

```
http://localhost/SiteVirtaulDirectory
```

Or you  may try opening the site from internet information server (IIS)

Open Internet Information Server, (type inetmgr and press enter on start->Run). Expand `Default Web sites`, then select any of the site, right click on it and select `Browse`.

Comment: 1) I created a virtual directory by, right click on default website (alias name: abc and physical path: to the inetpub\wwwrooot\abc folder) then followd localhot/abc  -> gives the same error 
2) other BROWSE option opens www.abc.com directly which shows PLESK/SONCIC hosting page.

Comment: @mesut, try browsing from IIS ?

Comment: yes, I'm in the webserver IIS self it self.

Comment: @mesut, not sure then buddy, wait for other people to response

Comment: I created a virtual directory in DEFAULT WEBSITE pointing to the website... then localhost\abc in browser.

Comment: ok it works now... After Add virtual directory in Default website, I had to do Convert to Application in Default website as well... so now I localhost\abc works fine... But it's so slow loading the pages, is this normal?